# CodeRunner Error - Not activating Virtual Environment before code execution

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

I am facing an issue while I am running a python program using CodeRunner extension on VS Code.
I am running it in a virtual environment that is already activated.

I have already set this settings:

[image]

I am getting this issue:
[image]

It is because while executing the program using CodeRunner, my virtual environment is not activated.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

In VS Code `settings.json`, add:
`"python.terminal.activateEnvironment": true`